# Go to "next" iteration in JavaScript forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

How do I go to the next iteration of a JavaScript `Array.forEach()` loop?

For example:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

myArr.forEach(function(elem){
  if (elem === 3) {
    // Go to "next" iteration. Or "continue" to next iteration...
  }

  console.log(elem);
});
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) only mention breaking out of the loop entirely, not moving to next iteration.

Comment: Don't use SO search. Use google, instead. This was the first search result for _"javascript foreach skip iteration"_

Answer (score 631, accepted):

You can simply `return` if you want to skip the current iteration.

Since you're in a function, if you `return` before doing anything else, then you have effectively skipped execution of the code below the `return` statement.

Comment: Nice hack. I would also choose this route. Some people (especially beginners) may misunderstand it as a stopping criterion, anyway.

Comment: In fact, it's _really not_  a hack. It's just how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Instead of using this, I was trying to make something like "continue" work without any success. Thanks for reminding me :).

Comment: In case some people don't see some of the explanations in other answers, this solution will only work with the forEach loop and will NOT work in a traditional for loop. For Each loop executes the callback function for each of the elements in the array so return will just move on to the next element / callback.

Comment: Of course. It can be a bit less obvious if you use the `.forEach((arg) => {});` syntax.

Answer (score 112):

JavaScript's forEach works a bit different from how one might be used to from other languages for each loops. If reading on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), it says that a *function* is executed for each of the elements in the array, in ascending order. To continue to the next element, that is, run the next function, you can simply return the current function without having it do any computation.

Adding a return and it will go to the next run of the loop:

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3,4];

myArr.forEach(function(elem){
  if (elem === 3) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(elem);
});
```

Output: 1, 2, 4

Comment: the 'return ' doesn't work well with forEach, however it works with for(let itemIndex in array)

Comment: @SunnySharma it works fine? How does `return` not work well with `forEach`?

Answer (score 10):

just return true inside your if statement

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4];

myArr.forEach(function(elem){
  if (elem === 3) {

      return true;

    // Go to "next" iteration. Or "continue" to next iteration...
  }

  console.log(elem);
});
```

Comment: No need for the `true`. Just `return;`