# How to wait for the response of all async fs.rename without blocking the process?

Tags: node.js, angular, fs

I built an Angular/Node app that renames files in network folders. The number of files it renames are between 300 to 500. I use await so I get notified when renaming is done. It takes 8-10minutes per run and it can't rename simultaneously since I am using await.

I need to pass the number of renamed files and I need to show the user that the renaming is already complete. If I don't use async/await, how can my angular front-end know that the renaming is completed?

My full code is in here: https://github.com/ericute/renamer

Here's where I'm having a trouble with:

```
    await walk(folderPath, function(err, results) {

        if (err) throw err;            

        results.forEach(file => {

            if (fs.lstatSync(file).isFile) {
                fileCounter++;
            }

            let fileBasename = path.basename(file);
            let filePath = path.dirname(file);

            if (!filesForRenaming[path.basename(file)]) {
                //In a javascript forEach loop,
                //return is the equivalent of continue
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399411/go-to-next-iteration-in-javascript-foreach-loop
                return;
            }

            let description = filesForRenaming[path.basename(file)].description;

            // Process instances where the absolute file name exceeds 255 characters.
            let tempNewName = path.resolve(filePath, description + "_" + fileBasename);            
            let tempNewNameLength = tempNewName.length;
            let newName = '';            

            if (tempNewNameLength > 255) {
                let excess = 254 - tempNewNameLength;
                if (description.length > Math.abs(excess)) {
                    description = description.substring(0, (description.length - Math.abs(excess)));
                }
                newName = path.resolve(filePath, description + "_" + fileBasename);                
            } else {
                newName = tempNewName;
            }

            renamedFiles++;
            // Actual File Renaming
            fs.renameSync(file, newName, (err) => {
                if (err) { 
                    errList.push(err);
                }
                renamedFiles++;
            });

        });

        if (Object.keys(errList).length > 0) {
            res.send({"status":"error", "errors": errList});
        } else {
            res.send({
                "status":"success",
                "filesFoundInDocData": Object.keys(filesForRenaming).length,
                "filesFound": fileCounter,
                "renamedFiles": renamedFiles,
                "startDate": startDate
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code should be throwing an error, since you don't await a function definition like that. Also, there's no reason to use it since you're using the *Sync versions of the fs commands, which are not asynchronous...

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, thanks for checking my question. If I don't use sync, how do I get notified that the renaming is complete? Here's what I need:
(1) Do the renaming
(2) Get notified that it is done without blocking the process.

Comment: The non-Sync versions allow you to pass callbacks. Or you can use `util.promisfy` to make them promises so you can use async/await. There are a number of tutorials and questions about doing things asynchronously in Node.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any sync methods you're basically blocking the event loop. You must change the whole structure of your code and start using promises everywhere. You should be able to create another service in angular that checks if the renaming process is completed using timeInterval and GET requests (the most easy way). For example, you could set angular to fetch data from "/isRenameCompleted" and alert the user if the result is true or something. To get real-time results you must switch to socket-io. A quickly solution for 1 client (cause you need to store unique IDs for each request and fetch promises accordingly) could be this one:

1: Create two global variables on top of your code

```
var filesStatus="waiting"
var pendingFiles=[]
```

2: Inside your renaming logic route push **every file** to the promise array using a for loop and start waiting asynchronously for the renaming process to finish

```
pendingFiles.push(fsPromises.rename(oldName,newName))
Promise.all(pendingFiles)
  .then(values => { 
    filesStatus = "done"
  })
  .catch(error => { 
    filesStatus = "error"
  });
filesStatus="pending"
```

3: Now add a new route `/isRenameCompleted` that will have a report logic like the following

```
router.get('/isRenameCompleted', (req, res, next) => {
 if (filesStatus==="pending"){
    res.end("please wait")
 } else if (filesStatus==="done"){
    res.end("done! your files renamed")   
 }
}
```

Comment: I've been rewriting my code based on your suggestion. I'll update my repo to reflect my changes once I'm done. Thanks a lot for the guidance!